# HTML5 video - progress bar and volume position not changing after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a typical code for video:

```
 <video id="video1" class="video-small" controls>
    <source src="video/film2.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="video-file">
    <source src="video/film2.webm" type="video/webm" class="video-file">
</video>
```

When I play the video, I'm not able to change the time on progress bar by clicking or change the volume.

I removed any other code that I had, now it's just the one above - why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide a live example, preferably a jsfiddle, to show us the issue. As it is we cannot reproduce the results you obtained

Answer (score 0):

As it just turned out, it was a conflict between iScroll plugin and the video element. When iScroll is enabled it both prevents the user from marking text and as well makes the progress bar and volume not responding to clicks.